# Zsh i named variable; "bad math expression: operand expected at `/houdi/loo...'"

Tags: zsh, variable

this's quite puzzling me, doing Zsh assignment using variable namedly `i`

```
% for i in '/houdi/lookup' '/komando/' ;{ echo value i = "$i" } 
zsh: bad math expression: operand expected at `/houdi/loo...'
```

but if changed to another name:

```
% for n in '/houdi/lookup' '/komando/' ;{ echo value i = "$n" } 
value i = /houdi/lookup
value i = /komando/
```

Any definitive explanation ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your `i` variable has likely been declared as integer or float by any one of `integer i`, `typeset -i i`, `float i`, `typeset -E i` or `typeset -F i`.

Then when you try to assign `/houdi/lookup`, the shell attempts to interpret it as an arithmetic expression and complains because the first `/` division operator there is missing its first operand.

Check with:

```
typeset -p i
```

Which will likely return something like one of:

```
typeset -i i=1
typeset -F i=0.0000000000
typeset -E i=1.2e+05
```

You can remove those integer/float attributes with `typeset +i i` (or `+E`, `+F` as relevant), with `-g` in functions to avoid making the variable locale.

`unset i` would also unset value and all attributes, so would declaring the variable local in a function or anonymous function, such as:

```
(){
  local i
  for i (/houdi/lookup /komando/) print -r value i = $i
}
```

(also using a less exotic form of `for` loop).

You could even make `$i` `private` in which case, the local `$i` will only be available to the anonymous function, not even to the functions it calls:

```
zmodload zsh/param/private

integer i=12
my_function() {
  print 'I expect $i to be integer'
  typeset -p i
}

(){
  private i
  for i (/houdi/lookup /komando/) {
    my_function
    print -r value i = $i
  }
}
```

Which gives:

```
I expect $i to be integer
typeset -g -i i=12
value i = /houdi/lookup
I expect $i to be integer
typeset -g -i i=12
value i = /komando/
```

See how `my_function` gets the original `$i`, not overridden by the anonymous function's private `$i`.